# RxJs6: OperatorFunction vs MonoTypeOperatorFunction

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6

I have the following code:

```
export class EventsChainComponent { 
    eventSubscriber:Subscription;

    constructor (protected eventService: EventService) {}


    public registerComponentsEvent(event:any) {
        // getOnEvent signature
        // (method) EventService.getOnEvent(): Observable<FormEvent>
        this.eventSubscriber = this.eventService.getOnEvent()
            .pipe(filter((formEvent: FormEvent) => {return formEvent.key == event.event}))
            .subscribe((formEvent: FormEvent) => {
                  ..........
            });
    }
```

When I compile, the compiler returns the following error:

> Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.

So, I search a little bit and I found the `RxJs6` operator filter API:

```
export declare function filter<T, S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number) => value is S, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, S>;
export declare function filter<T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number) => boolean, thisArg?: any): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
```

As you can see, the filter as 2 overloads methods, one returning `OperatorFunction` and another `MonoTypeOperatorFunction`.

Any one can tell me the difference between this 2 types? And any one knows how can I solve this error?

Note: The `FormEvent` class was created by me, and both `EventService` and `EventsChainComponent` has the same import that reference to the same class.

Comment: Are you typing `eventSubscriber`?

Comment: `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>` is equivalent to `OperatorFunction<T,T>`.

Comment: @Phix I change the question so you could have more info about my code.

Comment: @cartant if it is equivalent, why the compiler is giving such error?

Comment: It should be assignable, but there is insufficient information in your question to offer a reason. You'd need to show the type of the source observable. It must be if a different type to to type you've explicitly stated in the arrow function passed to `filter`.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean when you asked for to show the type of the source observable. If you want to know the type of object that is return when the `getOnEvent()` function is called, you can check the comment in the code available and you will see that is  `Observable<FormEvent>`. Even if I didn't understood your question, I hope that this comment answer it.

Comment: The only way that a `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>` is not assignable to an `OperatorFunction<T,T>` is if the type parameters - the `T`s - are different. Saying that the function returns `Observable<FormEvent>` in a comment is not particularly useful. Where does `FormEvent` event come from? Is it the same as the `FormEvent` you've used in that file? Is it a class? Who knows? Not me. My guess is that you have two `FormEvent` classes from different libraries. Or different installs of the same library.

Comment: @cartant Now I could understand. The `FromEvent` is a class that I create and is inside of the `event.service.ts` file. I check the imports and they reference to the same file and same class. This is, I guess, the first thing that I checked before I had post this problem.

Comment: Without a [mcve] I don't think this can be answered.

Comment: @cartant I found out the root of the problem: I was importing the same file and same class but from different folders. After I put the import from the same folder, I could solve the problem. If you want, you can put your comment that made this correction possible as an answer. Thank you

Comment: Just [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question; don't bother referencing the comment.

Comment: its better to check this answer
[Use a user-defined type-guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68324741/8607121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594026/rxjs6-operatorfunction-vs-monotypeoperatorfunction?noredirect=1#comment92145573_52594026) below, I found out the problem was that I imported the class from the same file name, but I had the same file in a different folder, under the src folder.

> The only way that a `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>` is not assignable to
>   an `OperatorFunction<T,T>` is if the type parameters - the `Ts` - are
>   different. Saying that the function returns `Observable<FormEvent>` in a
>   comment is not particularly useful. Where does FormEvent event come
>   from? Is it the same as the FormEvent you've used in that file? Is it
>   a class? Who knows? Not me. My guess is that you have two FormEvent
>   classes from different libraries. Or different installs of the same
>   library.

What I did was to remove one of the files and the error disappear.

Answer (score 5):

for other ppl having this issue:

I had the same issue. In my case the problem was with the Event object.

Both rxjs and angular/router have an event object so there was a name collision. 
What I did to solve this issue is to declare the @angular/router event with a different name and then use accordingly.

```
{Event as RouterEvent} from '@angular/router';
```

So after that: I use `Event` when i want to use rxjs.Event and `RouterEvent` when i want to use the @angular/router.Event. 
And the error is gone :)

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned solutions didn't work for me... I found this

```
filter((event): event is ActivationEnd => event instanceof ActivationEnd)
```

Credits to
https://gitmemory.com/issue/ReactiveX/rxjs/4947/518146427