# Angular Error TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Event>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event, Event>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Trying to troubleshoot this code,

```
import { Event, Router, RoutesRecognized, ActivationStart, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

...

this._router.events.pipe(
    filter((evt: Event) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized),
    map((evt: RoutesRecognized) => evt.state.root),
).subscribe((rootRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => (
    this._resolvedRoutes = this._getResolvedRoutes(rootRoute.children)
));
```

Which is producing this error,

```
ERROR: projects/acme/angular-ui/src/lib/services/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.service.ts:213:11 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Event>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event, Event>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
```

What exactly is the problem here? I'm guessing the `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Event>` function is the filter, but I have no idea what the `OperatorFunction<Event, Event>` why would there be two type-variables in the map? How do I resolve this?

Comment: You'll likely need to pass `filter` a user-defined type guard: `filter((evt: Event): evt is RoutesRecognized => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized)`

Comment: @cartant updated the question.

Comment: AFAICT, that's fixed the problem and has exposed another. `'Subscriber<T>' is not a class derived from 'Subscriber<T>'` suggests that you have multiple versions of RxJS installed - most likely via transitive dependencies. `yarn why rxjs` or `npm list rxjs` to see why/where.

Comment: oh my gawd.. Thanks. @cartant. Mind if I write up a self-answer for all this?

Comment: Sure. No worries.

Comment: @cartant interesting story, that fix in my answer adding rxjs to `tsconfig.json` makes it so that I no longer need the user-defined type-guards... ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Use a user-defined type-guard

I tried this previously, but this is the format you'll want:

```
this._router.events.pipe(
    filter((evt: Event): evt is RoutesRecognized => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized),
    map((evt: RoutesRecognized) => evt.state.root),
).subscribe((rootRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => (
    this._resolvedRoutes = this._getResolvedRoutes(rootRoute.children)
));
```

Now in my case, that produces this error:

```
ERROR: projects/acmeco/angular-ui/src/lib/services/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.service.ts:213:11 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/projects/acmeco/angular-ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types").OperatorFunction<import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/@angular/router/router").Event, import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/@angular/router/router").RoutesRecognized>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types").OperatorFunction<import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/@angular/router/router").Event, import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/@angular/router/router").RoutesRecognized>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/@angular/router/router").Event>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/projects/acmeco/angular-ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/@angular/router/router").Event>'.
      The types of 'source.operator.call' are incompatible between these types.
        Type '(subscriber: import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>, source: any) => import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types").TeardownLogic' is not assignable to type '(subscriber: import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/projects/acmeco/angular-ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>, source: any) => import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/projects/acmeco/angular-ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types").TeardownLogic'.
          Types of parameters 'subscriber' and 'subscriber' are incompatible.
            Type 'import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/projects/acmeco/angular-ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/ecarroll/code/js/myworkspace/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>'.
              Property 'isStopped' is protected but type 'Subscriber<T>' is not a class derived from 'Subscriber<T>'.
```

This error is because TypeScript is unsound, and you have two similarly named types. You can get more information about the conflict with `npm list rxjs`. You can fix this problem [following this blog post](https://blog.codewithdan.com/rxjs-error-types-of-property-source-are-incompatible/),

By adding to your `tsconfig.json`

```json
"paths": {
    "rxjs": [
      "node_modules/rxjs"
    ],
    "rxjs/*": [
      "node_modules/rxjs/*"
    ]
}
```

This will force all of your versions to use the same version of `rxjs`.

Comment: Thank you, problem cropped up out of no where in my case.  This solution worked for me

Comment: save my life , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation while writing an interceptor.

```
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        // clone event and do stuff
        return event;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

On 'filter' I got the following error:

> Type 'Observable<HttpEvent>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<HttpResponse>'.

The solution with "paths" in tsconfig.json didn't help, so I just worked it around by writing it the following way:

```
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // clone event and do stuff
        }
        return event;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Works like a charm. :)

Comment: While fixing your typings works, this acutally _should_ have worked to begin with. This solution is a workaround to a library export bug - I don't recommend it; rather the original issue should be resolved so we dont' have to write code in different ways.